# Confluent Kafka 101 tutorial follow through, Error: Get "https://confluent.cloud:8090/security/1.0/authenticate": dial tcp <ip>:8090: i/o timeout

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

I've been following through Confluent's official tutorial as found on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oI7VAS9KSS4

When it comes to the section (roughly starting 5'28'') about Confluent CLI, confluent login --save couldn't work without a --url flag, see the following screenshot
[image]
and by default the url is "https://confluent.cloud". So I had to do confluent login --save --url "https://cofluent.cloud" then was prompted to type in the username and password, and then I was stuck with this Error: Get "https://confluent.cloud:8090/security/1.0/authenticate": dial tcp :8090: i/o timeout Does anybody know how to solve this?

I'm using a Ubuntu on WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) on a Windows 10 PC.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this out by myself. Upgrading Confluent solved the problem.
Prior to upgrading I was on version v1.22.0, with which even confluent update wasn't an option. See the following screenshot for verification.
[image: Older Confluent CLI didn't support confluent update command]

The I upgraded with the command as shown below:
[image: Upgrading enables new command options]
If you compare before VS. after upgrading, you'll notice that some new command options were enabled, including the highlighted cloud-signup command.

The I ran the confluent cloud-signup command, was prompted to type in the following info: email, First Name, Last Name, Two-letter country code, Organization, Terms and Policy Agreement (y/n), and it told me "Error: Failed to sign up". Why? Because I had signed up all these info on https://confluent.cloud UI already. So if you've never signed up on the UI before, you definitely can do this via the CLI.
Since I already signed up, I ran command login. This time, with the newer version, it doesn't throw the complaint that login must be appended with the --url flag any more. And I could login without any issue.
After confluent login worked out, I ran confluent login --save and Confluent writes the credentials to a netrc file it creates called "<my_home_directory>.netrc" so that in the future I don't have to manually type in the credentials again.